# Insert initial phrase in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, moderncv

Is there a way to insert a phrase in the bibliography before the actual list of publications?
What I would like to do is to have a phrase like

> For a full list of related publications see www.example.com

followed by the standard list of publications.

I would use this with moderncv

Answer (score 1):

If you're ready to use the `biblatex` package, there's an easy solution. You may then use `\defbibnote{<name>}{<note>}` (see p. 77 of the biblatex documentation v. 2.8) which takes two arguments, a name and a content. Then call it up at the moment you wish to print the bibliography, like so

```
\printbibliography[prenote=<name>]
```

Here's an example:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@BOOK{childs_temperature,
  title = {Practical Temperature Measurement},
  publisher = {Butterworth - Heinemann},
  year = {2001},
  author = {Childs, Peter R N},
  address = {Great Britain},
  edition = {1},
  isbn = {0 7506 5080 X}
  }

  @PHDTHESIS{hashemian,
  author = {Hashemian, Hashem Mehrdad},
  title = {Measurements of dynamic temperatures and pressures in nuclear power plants},
  school = {{The University of Western Ontario}},
  year = {2011},
  type = {PhD {T}hesis}
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}

\firstname{Bob}
\familyname{Example}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{street}{city}
\mobile{123}
\email{123@server.com}


\usepackage[style=alphabetic,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\defbibnote{example}{% your note goes here, allows for formatting
                     % multiple paragraphs, etc.
}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[prenote=example]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do this without biblatex? I would prefer to stick to plain bibtex. Thanks!

Comment: @zuzzurezzu I don't know, sorry!